# Problema al insertar datos en mysql desde python

Tags: mysql, python

Estoy intentando ingresar una lista a una base de datos pero no e podido.

```
import MySQLdb    
class SubsistemaD():

def AgregarArchivo(self,Evento,NumDosis,Fecha,Hora,DosisReVi):
    self.Evento=Evento
    self.NumDosis=NumDosis
    self.Fecha=Fecha
    self.Hora=Hora
    self.DosisReVi=DosisReVi
    Eventos=open("Eventos.txt","a")
    Eventos.write("|")
    Eventos.write(self.Evento)
    Eventos.write(" "*(16-len(self.Evento)))
    Eventos.write("|")
    Eventos.write('%s'%self.NumDosis)
    Eventos.write(" "*(14))
    Eventos.write("|")
    Eventos.write(self.Fecha)
    Eventos.write(" "*(13-len(self.Fecha)))
    Eventos.write("|")
    Eventos.write(self.Hora)
    Eventos.write(" "*(7-len(self.Hora)))
    Eventos.write("|")
    Eventos.write(self.DosisReVi)
    Eventos.write(" "*(18-len(self.DosisReVi)))
    Eventos.write("|")
    Eventos.write("\n")
    Eventos.close()
    lista=["",self.Evento,self.NumDosis,self.Fecha,self.Hora,self.DosisReVi] 



    bd=MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root", passwd="password", db="Eventos")
    cursor=bd.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Almacen VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)",lista)
    bd.commit()
    bd.close()
```

Me sale el siguiente error

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "DosisRealId.py", line 684, in <module>
>     cargarInfoArchi("Dosis 
> saltada","1","6","5","2019",20,18,"R")    
>   File "DosisRealId.py", line 156, in cargarInfoArchi
>     Archivo.AgregarArchivo(Evento,NumDo,Fecha,HoraTotal,TipDo)
>   File "DosisRealId.py", line 144, in AgregarArchivo
>     cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Almacen VALUES 
> (?,?,?,?,?,?)",lista)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-     packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 187, in execute
>     query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args])
>    TypeError: not all arguments converted during string 
> formatting
> ```

Comment: seguro que ocupas php?